Is there a version of the delta method when taking the derivative of an estimator with respect to time for stochastic processes?
Suppose that $X$ is a stochastic process and $f$ some measurable function. Consider the random variable $S_t=\int_0^tf(X_s)\mathrm{d}s$ and an estimator $\hat{S}_t^n=\sum_{i=1}^{\lfloor t/n\rfloor}f(X_{t_i})(t_{i+1}-t_{i})$ where $t_j=0,...,n\lfloor t/n\rfloor$. Addionally, let $s_t^{n}=\frac{1}{b}\sum_{|t_j-t|\leq b}f(X_{t_j})$ and $s_t=\mathrm{d}S_t/\mathrm{d}t=f(X_t)$. Then $\hat{s}_t^n$ is an estimator for $s_t$. Now if we know that $\sqrt{n}(\hat{S}_t^n-S_t)\xrightarrow{d}N(0,\sigma^2)$ as $n\to\infty$, then what can we say about $\sqrt{n}(\hat{s}_t^n-s_t)$?
My first attempt to tackle the problem was to use the delta method, which simply tells us that if $\phi:\mathbb{R}^k\to\mathbb{R}^m$ is a measurable map that is differentiable at $\theta\in\mathbb{R}^k$, then if $r_n(T_n-\theta)\xrightarrow{d}T$ for some distribution $T$, estimator $T_n$ and numbers $r_n\to\infty$, then $r_n(\phi(T_n)-\phi(\theta))\xrightarrow{d}\phi'(\theta)Z$ where $\phi'$ denotes the derivative. However, I am not sure if one can even apply the delta method here, given that we are working with integrals and derivatives.
For some background: the application is for the quadratic variation of an Ito semimartingale. Namely, if $X_t=\int_0^tb_s\mathrm{d}s+\int_0^t\sigma_s\mathrm{d}W_s$ where $W$ denotes the Brownian motion, then $[X,X]_t=\int_0^t\sigma_s\sigma_s^\top\mathrm{d}s$ and
$$
[X,X]_t^n=\sum_{i=1}^n(\Delta X_{t_i})(\Delta X_{t_i}^\top)
$$
is an estimator for $[X,X]_t$. Now similar as before, suppose that we know that $\sqrt{n}([X,X]_t^n-[X,X]_t)\xrightarrow{d}N(0,\Gamma)$ for some covariance matrix $\Gamma$. Then as $\sigma_t\sigma_t^\top=\frac{\mathrm{d}[X,X]_t}{\mathrm{d}t}$, it must be that
$$
(\sigma_t\sigma_t^\top)_n=\frac{1}{b}\sum_{|t_i-t|\leq b}(\Delta X_{t_i})(\Delta X_{t_i}^\top)
$$
is an estimator for $\sigma_t\sigma_t^\top$ as $n\to\infty$ and $b\downarrow 0$. Here, we may assume that $b\sim g(n)$ for some function $g$ with $\lim_{x\to\infty}g(x)=0$ as to ensure that the convergence happens as both $n\to\infty$ and $b\downarrow 0$.
However, it is not clear to me how this transformation affects the asymptotic normality of the first estimator.

Not sure if directly helpful here, but the delta method is well known to hold in substantial generality - see e.g. van der Vaart Ch. 20.
